# How can I add history on my places autocomplete fragment?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-search

I have a autocomplete fragment search bar that I use for my map for the users destination, I got it from the documentation of places autocomplete, I want it to save the recent search the user made, is there any way I can do this? any comments or suggestion is greatly appreciated!!

Here is the code for my autocomplete fragment:

`

```
    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);
    }

    PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

    LatLng angelesCityLatLng = new LatLng(15.1445, 120.5887);

    autocompleteFragment.setLocationBias(RectangularBounds.newInstance(
            new LatLng(angelesCityLatLng.latitude - 0.1, angelesCityLatLng.longitude - 0.1),
            new LatLng(angelesCityLatLng.latitude + 0.1, angelesCityLatLng.longitude + 0.1)

    ));

    // Specify the types of place data to return.
    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));

    // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());


            // Get the LatLng of the selected place
            LatLng selectedPlaceLatLng = place.getLatLng();

            // Define a new CameraPosition with desired zoom level
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(selectedPlaceLatLng) // Sets the center of the map to the selected    place's LatLng
                    .zoom(20) // Desired zoom level
                    .build();

            // Move the camera to the new position
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            // Remove the previous marker if it exists
            if (markerSelectedLoc != null) {
                markerSelectedLoc.remove();
            }

            // Create a new marker for the selected location
            markerSelectedLoc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(selectedPlaceLatLng)
                    .flat(true));

            checkDistanceToCustomRoutes(selectedPlaceLatLng, mlocation);

            

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }`
```

Comment: Since the autocomplete fragment already had built in features, I don't think there's much you can do to customize it. It's either you use a separate UI interface to save the recent searches, or you can file a Feature Request if you want in this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker